# Why to ring bell while entering temples?

Tags: temple, worship

When I entered a temple, I saw people ringing the bell, and also Hindus keep  small  bells in their houses, which they ring during worship. What is reason behind it, and also notice about "dhup" ?

Comment: Ringing bell while entering Temples is probably to notify God that " i have come to your house". Just like we ring door bells while entering any other houses.

Comment: BTW what is notice about Dhup? Dhup= Incense but notice?